# Pandas: Extracting just the Calendar Year from Datetime column

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timestamp, time-series

I have a Dataframe with a column alike the following column:

```
df['Schedule'] =
...
2012-12-31
2013-01-01
2013-01-02
2013-01-03
2013-01-04
2013-01-05
2013-01-06
2013-01-07
2013-01-08
2013-01-09
```

And so on from 1981 to 2015. The elements of the column are pandas.tslib.Timestamp.

I needed to create another column where I had to extract only the year.

So I did the following command:

```
df['Year'] = df['Schedule'].dt.year
```

It partially worked because I need the years to match with the date from calendar year (my dataset is composed of matchups of a NBA season)/
To be clear instead of:

```
2012-12-31    2012
2013-01-01    2013
```

I need:

```
2012-12-31    2013
2013-01-01    2013
...
2013-09-27    2014
...
2014-04-06    2014
```

Does anyone have an efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: How do months map to the season?

Comment: My observations (inputs) are all matchups from 1981 to 2015. The beginning of each season is around October and the regular season (before the playoffs) ends in mid-April. So the concerning months are the following: 09,10,11,12,01,02,03,04. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you're saying, it seems like September is the breakpoint for NBA season year.  If so, your best bet would be to `apply` a custom `lambda`, like this one:

```
df["year"] = df["schedule"].apply (lambda x : x.year if x.month < 9 else x.year + 1)
```

If you give me more info on NBA season months I can clean this up.

Here's a test program yielding correct outputs for your sample:

```
import dateutil

df = DataFrame ({
    "schedule" :
    Series ([
        "2012-12-31",
        "2013-01-01",
        "2013-09-27",
        "2014-04-06"
    ]).apply(dateutil.parser.parse)
})
df["year"] = df["schedule"].apply (lambda x : x.year if x.month < 9 else x.year + 1)
df
```

[image]

[Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#row-or-column-wise-function-application) is one of the places where the pandas documentation first begins to introduce using `lambda` functions with `apply`.

Comment: To give you more information, my dataset is composed of the regular season schedule (from October to mid-April). Your code sounds pretty good but why does ".apply(dateutil.parser.parse)"?

Comment: Thx for accepting.  The `.apply(dateutil.parser.parse)` was just to set up the sample data to make the `schedule` column into a `datetime` type, which I assume was the type of your original dataset column too.

Comment: Yes! Thx for your help.